# Как исправить ошибку No module named 'flask_wtf'?

Tags: python, flask

Изучаю Flask по учеблику [Мега-Учебник Flask](https://habr.com/post/346342/) и в третьей части при разборе web -форм получаю ошибку

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_wtf'
```

Судя по результатам в поисковике, распространенная ошибка, но никак исправить не смог. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить? Код у меня в точности такой же, как в учебнике.

Comment: дык, установить `flask_wtf`... в учебнике же написано: `pip install flask-wtf` — ты или пропустил это, или проигнорировал ошибку...

Comment: Fat-Zer, в том-то и дело, что установил

Comment: без полного точного набора действий, которые привели к ошибке и информации об окружении — не верю... или всё же не установил, или установил для другой версии питона, или где-то (в `import`'е опечатка)

Comment: В виртуальных окружениях не запутались случайно? Нужен точный набор действий, да

Comment: Прошу прощения, видимо, все же что-то напутал. Сделал заново и заработало. Спасибо за комменты.